# checkbox to update attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

[Updated a bit] I have a Task model that has a :completed boolean attribute. If I click on it I want it to execute the 'finish' method. The main problem is that I am displays a series of checkboxes in a list and subsequent checkboxes after the first one are ignored. The method is never called for the given task/checkbox combo.

I have this chunk of code in my view:

```
<% current_user.tasks.each do |t|%>
      <% if t.completed == false %>
          <%= check_box_tag :completed, true, checked = false   %>
          <%= observe_field :completed, :url => { :controller => 'tasks', :action => :finish , :id => t.id },
              :frequency => 0.25,
              :update => :completed,
              :with => true
          %>
```

and my finish method looks like this:

```
def finish
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
      new = {:completed => true}
      @task.update_attributes(new)
      render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html "taskListing", :partial => 'home/task_listing'
 end
```

Comment: are you looking for the javascript which posts to the finish action or are you having trouble with something else?

Comment: I added a little more information above. Basically if I have more than one checkbox (created in a do loop) ... subsequent checkboxes after the first are ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out:

Here it is:

```
 <% current_user.tasks.each do |t|%>
          <% if t.completed == false %>
              <%= check_box_tag t.id, true, checked = false   %>
              <%= observe_field t.id, :url => { :controller => 'tasks', :action => :finish , :id => t.id },
                  :frequency => 0.25,
                  :update => :completed,
                  :with => true
              %>
          <%= link_to t.title , t %> - <%= t.due_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y %X %p")%>
```